# Can I gather a list of directories and iterate over them without stopping when an error occurs?

Tags: c#, winforms

If I loop through a list of directories, I have to put the `try{}catch{}` block outside of the loop. If I put it inside of the loop, an error can occur on that directory before I even get a chance to catch it. Putting the try catch inside of the loop is the ideal scenario though, because it would allow me to catch the error and continue on to the next directory.

But since I'm forced to put the try catch on the outside, it will error on a directory and won't continue on to the next directory.

```
try
{
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        queue.Enqueue(subDir);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get each directory, one at a time?

Comment: if you don't have any try-catches, what are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: can you expand more on what you mean by the phrase "an error can occur on that directory before I even get a chance to catch it".

Answer (score 2):

I assume the error you're getting is on the call to `Directory.GetDirectories(path)`.  If that's the case, do this in the try/catch before entering the loop.

```
string[] directories;

try
{
    directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
}

foreach (string subDir in directories)
{
    queue.Enqueue(subDir);
}
```

[`Queue<T>.Enqueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t249c2y7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't throw any exceptions so you don't need a try/catch block for it.

Note that you'll need to either `return;` after an exception is thrown or check for `directories` being null, otherwise entering the `foreach` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, nothing prevents you from using two `try/catch` like this:

```
try
{
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        try
        {
            queue.Enqueue(subDir);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do whatever you want with the error.
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to catch the specific error? If not, just fail fast. Directory.Exists will return false on <s>both errors thrown and</s> a non-existent path:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(path) {
    //error handling here
}

foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    queue.Enqueue(subDir);
}
```

**Correction:** See MrBlue comments below regarding directory access.

Comment: If the user doesn't have permission to read the directory, `Directory.Exists(path)` will still return true, but `Directory.GetDirectories(path)` will throw an exception.

Comment: MrBlue, just tested this and you are correct. The way I read the msdn for Exists() was this scenario should return false: "If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the directory, the Exists method will return false." Thanks for my lesson of the day!

Comment: Probably worth clarifying: `Exists` and `GetDirectories` need read permissions at two different levels.  `Exists` needs read permissions for the _parent_ of the path being checked, while `GetDirectories` needs read permissions for the path itself.  Basically, even if you can't see inside the path, if you have read permissions for it's parent, you can still see if it exists or not.